# Regression analysis and new data

Tags: regression

I've got X and Y variables for performing a linear regression on them. How can I calculate the probability that a new entry belongs to the model I have fitted on X and Y?

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you're looking for the likelihood of the residual for the new observation, where the residuals are distributed $Normal(0,\sigma^2)$ and $\sigma$ is estimated by your model as $s^2$. I.e.:

$$ 
\hat{y} = X\beta \\
r = y-\hat{y} \\
p(r) = (2\pi s^2)^{-1/2} exp \left( -\frac{r^2}{2s} \right) $$

Comment: Can you explain better what is the residual? Is it the squared error?

Comment: The residual is the difference between your observed $y$ and your predicted $y$ (denoted in my answer as $\hat{y}$). It's just another word for the error term. The "squared error" is the square of the residual.

Comment: Where the formula for calculating the residual probability comes from? Shouldn't I calculate the probability of the world state w, given the parameters and the data?

Comment: That formula is just the PDF for the normal distribution. Simple linear regression assumes that the residuals follow a normal distribution.

Comment: No, simple linear regression does **not** assume that the residuals follow a normal distribution. (An exception where this assumption is actually used is when you want exact finite sample distributions of parameter estimates. But this is an exception, not the general case.)

Comment: You can find a least squares fit without making the assumption that the error terms are normally distributed, but "simple linear regression" definitely assumes the error terms are normally distributed. Here's the model I'm referring to as simple linear regression: $\epsilon \sim Normal(0,\sigma^2)$, $y=X\beta + \epsilon$ . Maybe I'm using the wrong name for this model? Pretty sure this is simple linear regression.

Comment: In sec. 11.3.3 of Casella and Berger (Simple Linear Regression - Models and Distribution Assumptions), they describe to variants of "simple linear regression:" the "Conditional Normal Model" which is what I described, and the "Bivariate Normal Model" which is different from the model I described, but which still makes a normality assumption. In sec. 14.2 of Gelman's Bayesian Data Analysis (Bayesian analysis of the classical regression model), he refers to the model I described as "ordinary linear regression."